# Ordenar array em rails

Tags: array, ruby-on-rails, classificação

Não consigo ordenar minha array em ordem de id decrescente.

```
<%@vendas = Vendas.find(:all,:order=>"id, DESC")%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, não sei como seu código funciona, pois o método find requer o ID do objeto que se quer resgatar.

Procure utilizar a sintaxe nova do Ruby em vez dos rockets. Procure também  utilizar espaçamento para seu código ficar mais legível.

O código correto para fazer o que você deseja é o seguinte:

```
<% @vendas = Vendas.order("id DESC") %>
```

Outra coisa, recomendo mover esta linha de código para um controller,  pois não é uma boa prática deixar a visão responsável por tarefas como estas.

No seu controller você poderia fazer: `@ultimas_vendas = Vendas.order("id DESC")`
E na visão apenas chamar @ultimas_vendas.

**É importante ressaltar que não é retornado um array, e sim um ActiveRecord_Relation.**

Answer (score 0):

Método correto:

```
<%@vendas = Vendas.find(:all,:order=>"id DESC")%>
```

Comment: Isso é a resposta?

Comment: @Math parece-me que sim, a diferença é a virgula.